# Storing CFAbsoluteTime to nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, store, nsnumber

I want to store CFAbsoluteTime in NSMutablearray. Can I add like this ?

```
CFAbsoluteTime time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
[tapTimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)time]];
```

If so, after I store that, I need to retrieve that one and convert to CFAbsoluteTime for later calculation. I would like to know how to do.

Comment: Use modern syntax: `[tapTimes addObject:@(time)];`.

Comment: How shall I retrieve and use as CFAbsoluteTime?

Comment: My comment was for adding the value. You get the value as shown in the answer you accepted. But you can use modern syntax there too: `CFAbsoluteTime time = [tapTimes[someIndex] doubleValue];`

Comment: aww..it is great..I can use that method also.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. To get the value back as a `CFAbsoluteTime`, do:

```
CFAbsoluteTime time = [[tapTimes objectAtIndex:…] doubleValue];
```